# Deployment QML app with minimum Qt libraries

Tags: qt, gcc, qml, qmake

I have an app wirtten with C++ (just simple QML loader) and QML (all GUI and logics).
Now I want to create some package for deployment to other systems. Currently I need it only for Windows so I create a package with Inno Setup.

I packaged my exe file and couple of Qt libraries. To view what libraries I need I used Dependency Walker. But I was surprized that my app was linked with unused libraries:

- Qt5Multimedia.dll
- Qt5MultimediaWidgets.dll
- Qt5Sensors.dll
- Qt5Positioning.dll

Also I see these libraries in compiler output: `-lQt5Positioning -lQt5Sensors ...` etc.

**But I don't use no multimedia no sensors no positioning at all!!**

In .pro file I use that:

```
QT += qml quick sql widgets xml webkitwidgets
```

So my qustion - how can I compile my app without these superfluous libraries?

Comment: Whatever you put into the QT += line is subject to dependency analysis. Presumably stuff from one of those modules - quick perhaps? - depends on other modules.

Comment: Yes, it maybe WebKit requires additional libraries. Or possible QtQuick. But actually I don't need this functionality. No multimedia, no sensors etc. Is it possible to compile without these unnecessary libraries?

Comment: Maybe a ``QT -= sensors positioning multimedia`` will help. Never tried these though. Its possible they get ignored if a module has hard depencies on these.